# Check CRL OpenSSL C

Tags: c++, c, openssl, gsoap

I'm developing a secure webserver in C/C++ using gSoap and OpenSSL. I need to check a CRL - struct X509_CRL - to see wheter or not a certificate - struct X509 - is revoked. I don't know how to do it and it doesn't seem I can find anything on the web. OpenSSL is poorly, poorly documented, all I can find are command line examples I don't need! Thanks to everyone would be so nice to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `crypto/x509/x509_vfy.s` in `openssl` sources. There is a function named `X509_verify_cert(X509_STORE_CTX *)` that probably do what you need to do. Anyway, this file can help you in your search.